# make a method available to all Activities

Tags: android

I have a method "InitView", I want to call it in every Activity, I create a class "Helper" and in it my method I make it static and pass Activity like parameter.

I'm wondering if its the best solution and if there is no memory leak or something like that.
here is my code:

```
public class Helper {

    public static void intView(Activity activity) {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        Drawable background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.gradient_bg, null);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        //window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the concept of **Inheritance**.

Make a base/parent class, which can be inherited to all its child classes where you want to use the functions.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
     
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         initView();
     }

     private void initView(){
 
         Window window = activity.getWindow();
         Drawable background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.gradient_bg, null);
         window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
         window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
         //window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));    
         window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

     }
}
```

You can extend this BaseActivity to your activities

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity {

}
```

Now, this will prevent method leaks and getting rid of `static` keyword.